# Vue.js + socket.io how to update props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So this is my user list component for Vue. Socket.io returns a list of currently active users for example [{name:Fluxed,rank:Admin}] and I want it to auto-update the element. How can I update the prop element then make it show a change?

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
    <div style="float:right;width:30%;border-left:1px solid black;padding:1%;">
      <b>Users</b>
      <b-list-group style="max-width: 300px;" >
        <b-list-group-item class="align-items-center" v-for="value in userList2" v-bind:key="value.name" >
          <b-avatar class="mr-3"></b-avatar>
          <span class="mr-auto">{{ value.name }}</span>
          <b-badge>{{ value.rank }}</b-badge>
        </b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
      <ul class="list-group">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import $ from 'jquery'
var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
socket.on('update', function (users){
      this.userList = users;
      console.log(this.userList)
}) 
import VueJwtDecode from "vue-jwt-decode";
export default {
  
  name: 'app',
  props: {
    userList2: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  data() {
    
    return {
      user: {},
      componentKey: 0,
      userList: this.userList2,
      
    };
  },
  
  created () {
    // get socket somehow
    socket.on('update', function (users){
      console.log(this.userList)
      this.userList = users;
      console.log(this.userList)
    }) 
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserDetails() {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
      let decoded = VueJwtDecode.decode(token);
      let response = await this.$http.post("/update", decoded);
      let urank = response.data.rank;
      this.user = decoded;
      this.user.rank = urank;
    },
    logUserOut() {
      localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
    
  },
}
</script>
```

How can I make the Vue bootstrap group item auto-update once a change happens with socket.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overview:**

You could `$emit event` with an updated list back to the parent and then update the `data` property in the parent component. That is because you should not directly modify `props`.

---

**Example:**

In your child component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

data() {
 return {
  socket: io()
 }
},
props: {
 userList2: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => []
 }
},
created() {
  this.socket.on('update', (users) => {
   this.$emit('updateListEv', users);
  })
}
```

then in your parent component:

```
<childNameComponent @updateListEv="updateList"></childNameComponent>
```

then you need a method in your parent component to actually update the `data` property with the data passed back from the child component.

```
methods: {
  updateList(updatedList) {
   this.userList2 = updatedList
  }
}
```

---

**Note:**

You should be able to use your `prop` directly if you do it that way so there is no need for setting additional `data` property in your child component - `userList: this.userList2`.

You would be looping through `userList2` in this case - the same way that you are doing right now - `v-for="value in userList2"`

You can also see that in this case, we initialise the socket as a `data` property so that we could use it in our Vue instance.

---

**Edit:**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
data() {
  return {
    socket: io(),
    usersList: this.userList2
  }
},
props: {
 userList2: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => []
 }
},
created() {
  this.socket.on('update', (users) => {
   this.userList = users
  })
}
```

in your `HTML` template loop through the user list:

```
v-for="value in usersList"
```

---

**Using socket.io with Vue.js and Node.js full example:**

In your backend (Node.js):

```
//setting up sockets
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('sendUpdateList', function(data) {
    io.emit('listUpdate', data)
  });
})
```

Sending an update from the component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

data() {
 return {
  socket: io(),
  usersList: []
 }
},
methods: {
 this.socket.emit('sendUpdateList', {usersList: this.usersList})
}
```

Listening to socket in the component:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

data() {
 return {
  socket: io(),
  usersList: []
 }
},
created() {
  this.socket.on('listUpdate', (data) => {
   this.usersList = data.usersList
  })
}
```

Comment: Love your answer but it still doesn't show it on the page. How can I make it render the childNameComponent but not the page?

Comment: childNameComponent is just an example of your component name that you use in your parent component (that is your list component). Where do you get your `props` from in this case?

Comment: Props are from socket.io users

Comment: That sounds odd. I am not sure whether I understand the problem correctly. I have edited the answer. Can you please try it out? Also, please check your console if there are any errors.

Comment: Still doesn't show anything but it is there. How do I update it?

Comment: Added the flow of working with `socket.io` to the answer. Have a look. I hope it clarifies a few things.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to say since we can't run your code, but having a quick look at it I think it is as simple as this:

Replace the `userList2` in `v-for="value in userList2"` to `userList`.

If you are going to work more with sockets and Vue, I think the vue-socket.io is quite a useful library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside the callback of `socket.on('update'` is not what you think it is (it is not the vue component), so assigning to `this.userList` won't trigger any changes in the vue component).

Use and arrow function as the callback so that it uses the surrounding `this` (which is your component) like so:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import $ from 'jquery'
import VueJwtDecode from "vue-jwt-decode";

var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: {
    userList2: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  data() {
    
    return {
      user: {},
      componentKey: 0,
      userList: this.userList2,
      
    };
  },
  
  created () {
    socket.on('update', users => {      // arrow function here so 'this' keyword inside will refer to your vue component
      this.userList = users;            // either this one
      this.userList2 = users;           // or this one (I don't know why you are using two props for this btw)
    }) 
  },
  // ...
}
```

Read more about `this` and why arrow functions don't have them in this other SO question: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/9867451)